# How to create network-truststore.jks for differenct nodes running on different virtual machine

Tags: corda, production

How to create network-truststore.jks for different nodes running on different virtual machines on google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like the [CENM](https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.1/quick-start.html) to create a private network. It provides a PKI tool which is configurable, and you could use this tool to create all the required certificates.

Another option is to use the [network-bootstrapper](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-bootstrapper.html) tool to create a local network and then copy individual node folders created in build/nodes folder to individual VM's. Make sure you change the IP address in node.conf to the correct VM's public address.